# I want to be informed if my app is no longer visible or killed

Tags: android

I want to run a SERVICE when my app is no longer visible for example if the user pressed home button or killed my app.
how can I implement that?

Comment: Which tutorial you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run that service in `onStop` of a Activity. 
`Onstop` is Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user.
It won't work if the application crashes.

Comment: Unfortunately, `onStop()` is called everytime an `Activity` recedes into the background. If an `Activity` recedes into the background, it doesn't mean the app has gone into the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can run that service in onPause of a Activity.  OnPause is Called when the user press home button. For Back Button, OnStop is Called. It won't work if the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onPause` method, which runs when user presses home button and your application go in background, and `onDestroy` which called back when your application is been killed.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)